# How to calculate arcsin(sgn(x)√|x|)?

Tags: r, transformation

I'm trying to arcsine squareroot data lying on `[-1,1]`. Using `transf.arcsine` from the `metafor` package produces `NaNs` when trying to squareroot the negative datapoints. Conceptually, I want to use `arcsin(sgn(x)√|x|)` i.e. square the absolute value, apply its previous sign, then arcsine transform it. The trouble is I have no idea how to begin doing this in R. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
x <- seq(-1, 1, length = 20)
asin(sign(x) * sqrt(abs(x)))
```

or as a function

```
trans.arcsine <- function(x){
  asin(sign(x) * sqrt(abs(x)))
}
trans.arcsine(x)
```

Answer (score 4):

Help in R is just `help()` or `help.search()`.  So, let's try the obvious,

```
> help(arcsin)
No documentation for ‘arcsin’ in specified packages and libraries:
```

OK, that's not good.  But it must be able to trig... let's try something even simpler.

```
help(sin)
```

There's all the trig functions.  And I note, there's a link to `Math` on the page.  Clicking that seems to provide all of the functions you need.  It turns out that I could have just typed..

```
help(Math)
```

also,

```
help.search('trigonometry')
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but my question isn't really about how to sine data. It's more about how to extract the SIGN of the data, how to squareroot an absolute value, and how to assign the previously extracted sign to the result of the squareroot. I hope I was clear in the original post.

Comment: I've rolled back your title edit as, like I've explained, it's not 'just finding basic math functions' that I'm looking for help with.

Comment: And if you followed the link to the Math help it's all there, `sign` is the `sign` function, `abs` for absolute... just read the help.  It is just basic math.  I thought you might prefer knowing how to find help to do more than one equation.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar prob. I wanted to arcsine transform most of the dataset "logmeantd.ascvr" & approached it in this manner:

First make are data range has been transformed b/t -1 and 1 (in this case they were expressed as percentages):

```
logmeantd.ascvr[1:12] <- logmeantd.ascvr[1:12] * 0.01
```

Next apply the square root function, sqrt():

```
logmeantd.ascvr[1:12] <- sqrt(logmeantd.ascvr[1:12])
```

lastly apply the arc sine function, asin():

```
logmeantd.ascvr[1:12] <- asin(logmeantd.ascvr[1:12])
```

*note in this instance I had excluded the MEAN variable of my dataset because I wanted to apply a log function to it, log():

```
 logmeantd.ascvr$MEAN <- log(logmeantd.ascvr$MEAN)
```